# R - Efficient selective sum of highdimensional sparse dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I it seems that my PC is to slow for summing this:

```
library(plyr)

# Function for creating random n pseudowords of predefined length needed for colnames. Proposed by: http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2008/12
colnamesString <- function(n=10000, lenght=12) /18/generate-random-string-name/
{
  randomString <- c(1:n)                  # initialize vector
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                    lenght, replace=TRUE),
                             collapse="")
  }
  return(randomString)
}

set.seed(1)
myColnames <- strsplit(colnamesString(10000,8), " ") # vector with 10000 random colnames of length 8
datfra <- data.frame(matrix(data = sample(c(0,1),(10000*1500), replace= TRUE), nrow= 1500, ncol= 10000, dimnames= list(NULL, myColnames))) # creates a dandom dataframe with the colnames created before with binary (not essential, for readablity) values.
datfra <- cbind(datfra, colID=(sample(c(1:150),1500, replace= TRUE))) # creates IDs vector
datfra[1:5,c(1:3,10001)] # small section of the created dataframe, with coresponding IDs

coldatfra <- ddply(datfra[1:50,c(1:5,10001)], .(colID), numcolwise(sum)) # The solution for a small subset of the big dataframe.
#It works fine! But if applied to the whole dataframe it never ends computing.

# Therefore the challange is how to compute efficiently with an ALTERNATIVE approach to this?
coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), numcolwise(sum)) # stopped after 15m of computing
```

*EDITstart*

The aim is to sum up, for each unique `colID` all entries in all columns, column-wise. Expcted result is:

```
coldatfra[1:10,c(1:5,10001)] # Small subset of rows, only for five columns + colID colum:
   gnzUcTWE D3caGnLu IZnMVdE7 gn0nRltB ubPFN6Ip colID
1         3        4        5        5        6    12
2        10        8        7        4        7    24
3         4        8        4        5        5    36
4         2        4        6        5        5    36
5         5        6        6        6        7    55
6         5        2        4        3        4    42
7         5        3        6        5        4    63
8         8       12        8        8       10   160
9         7        3        5        3        3    90
10        2        3        1        2        2    60
```

*EDITend*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I think I misunderstood OP, here is my new understanding that preserves columns:

```
library(data.table)
res <- data.table(datfra)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=colID]
# user  system elapsed 
# 8.32    0.05    8.38
```

This is about 4.5x times faster than the `ddply` version.  Unfortunately, this is still somewhat slow.

---

OLD STUFF:

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can do this much faster by first calculating the row sums for all the columns, and then aggregating by group:

```
datfrasum <- 
  data.frame(
    sums=rowSums(datfra[, names(datfra) != "colID"]), 
    colID=datfra$colID
  )
ddply(datfrasum, .(colID), colSums)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.37    0.02    0.39
```

In this case, the very slow step was trying to generate all the groups for so many columns, so this is substantially faster.  Generally speaking, you want to use `data.table` or `dplyr` instead of `plyr` as the latter is now a generation behind the other two in terms of performance, but even with those you should consider the column collapsing first.

Here is a `data.table` alternative, though because it does not do the rowsums first it is actually slower than the method above:

```
library(data.table)
dattab <- data.table(datfra)
dattab[, sum(unlist(.SD)), by=colID]
```

If you were to do the rowsums and use `data.table`, that would be faster still.

Comment: Can you please adapt the code in order to be able to rate and accept it as the right soltion? On the other hand, if you prefer, I can change it too. Thank you again (it haunted me for two days) and a nice day :)

Comment: (Sorry this message should be the first but I deleted the original by mistake) Thank you much! Very nice :) Actually I needed a slightly different result, but I could derive it from your answer (see added EDIT). The proper code for my problem is: coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), colSums) Can you please briefly explain what the difference is to coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), numcolwise(sum))

Comment: @alex, I'll look at this in a bit (busy now); in the meantime, can you recreate your expected result by running `set.seed(1)` before you do anything so that I can know exactly what's going on?

Comment: @alex Thank you. The set.seed(1) result is corresponding to what I need. I.e. `(coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), colSums))[1:10,c(1:5,10001)]`.

Comment: @alex, see my update.  I had not understood what you wanted.  Unfortunately the new solution is not as fast.

Comment: Thank you again. Please note the first and second comment above. Most importantly "The proper code for my problem is: `coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), colSums)` Can you please briefly explain what the difference is to `coldatfra <- ddply(datfra, .(colID), numcolwise(sum))` is"

Comment: the update on top has an `data.table` output. I tried to reconvert it to a `data.frame` by `as.data.frame.matrix(coldatfra)` (`res` - in your variant) but it doesen't work. Do you know a solution to this? Is there a possibility to do this WITHOUT loosing any attributes?

Comment: @alex, `as.data.frame(res)` should work.  Separately, `colSums` and `numcolwise(sum)` basically do the same thing (try: `df <- data.frame(1:3, 1:3, 1:3); numcolwise(sum)(df); colSums(df)`)

Comment: It works! You are a true Hero! Thank you much! Sorry for the delay could not be online. Best wishes and a nice day.